# Custom Background Image From UIPickerController

Tags: ios, background

Building an app which gives the users the option to change the backgroud of the app.
Currently using this code to save images from the picker.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    customImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(customImage);
    NSString *fetchCustomImage = @"userCustomImage.png";
    NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentDirectory = [path objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *fullPathToFile = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fetchCustomImage];

    [data writeToFile:fullPathToFile atomically:YES];

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

    [self performSelector:@selector(fetchCustomBackground)]
}
```

Then calls a void to display the image

```
- (void)fetchCustomBackground
{
    //Fetch Background Image
    NSString *fetchUserImage = @"userCustomImage.png";
    NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentDirectory = [path objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *fullPath = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fetchUserImage];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:fullPath];
    [background setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:data]];

}
```

In the viewDidLoad

```
[self performSelector:@selector(fetchCustomBackground)];
```

At the moment the app is very slow I guess because every time the view loads it has to fetch the image, is there a way to save it so you don't have to call it every time the view loads?

Comment: please note that this has absolutely nothing to do with Xcode. Xcode is just the IDE you use to write iOS apps. Your quesiton, on the other hand, is purely programming-related.

Comment: You can call a method in the same class like this: `[self fetchCustomBackground];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to update your function like this.

```
- (void)fetchCustomBackground
{

dispatch_queue_t concurrentQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_async(concurrentQueue, ^{

__block NSData *data;

dispatch_sync(concurrentQueue, ^{ 
    //Fetch Background Image
    NSString *fetchUserImage = @"userCustomImage.png";
    NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentDirectory = [path objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *fullPath = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fetchUserImage];
    data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:fullPath];
});
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
[background setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:data]];
}); });
}
```

Comment: Use of undeclared identifier 'data'

Comment: Try now, I'm not on computer so I can't check

Comment: Ok works great its faster now, however the image loads a fraction after the view, any ideas?

Comment: Sure, it takes some time to load the image. Now is the main queue not stucked so it can perform some other tasks while the image is loading in background. If you want to load your view with background loaded, try to downsize your background picture or if it's not possible and you need big picture you can do some kind of preloading...

Comment: What sort of preloading?

Comment: It's up to you, I don't know your app. You can use the GCD as I mentioned. The idea is to preload all the stuff you need and then shows the view at once. You know that from games for sure :)

Answer (score 0):

I see no problem with loading a a single picture from Documents. But for sure, if you are loading a large picture and doing simultanely some UI updates, it can be problem. You have to free main thread using Grand Central Dispatch.